# Числительное "один"

Tags: числительные

Меняется ли роль в предложении в зависимости от значения?

1)Утром мы выяснили, что одно животное куда-то исчезло. (числительное (1)- подлежащее)

2)Одно животное вечно ходит за вами, вы знаете, кто это? (в значении неопределенного местоимения [некое] - определение)

Или значение не играет роли?

Comment: Вопрос был о ролях в предложении, а не частях речи.

Comment: Мне кажется некое не уместно. Некий город - какой-то город, один город - один из городов. Одно из животных вечно ходит за вами - подлежащее. Тут водятся животные. Одно вечно ходит за вами. А вот: один окунь ловится = только этот вид рыбы ловится, какая рыба ловится - один окунь, тут, может быть, определение. Ловится окунь? - "один ловится" не ответишь, но скажешь "один он(окунь) и ловится". Один окунь ловится, другой не ловится - подлежащее. За вами ходят одни (+лишь) животные, -тут тоже, наверное, определение.